# "everything": is it "it" or "they"

Tags: pronouns, countability

Which pronoun should be used with "everything"?

I tend to believe that the following is correct:

> I will do everything as soon as **it** can be done.

but the following also makes sense, considering that "everything" implies "more than 1":

> I will do everything as soon as **they** can be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Everything" logically means that there are multiple things and one is talking about **each**  of those things. Hence, it is considered singular.  ([source](https://www.myqbook.com/GrammarConcept/25/Everybody-everything-everyone-singular-or-plural))

So the singular pronoun, "**it**" will be used.

Comment: I doubt the source is actually reliable since there's nothing wrong with "Everybody brought their jacket".

Comment: @user178049: "Their" in this case is the gender-neutral singular pronoun. Unfortunate choice, from my point of view, but we have to take it the way it is.

Comment: @BellaSwan: singular "verb"?

Comment: @virolino the verb used for singular nouns :)

Comment: I meant... **"it"** is not a verb. **"Everything"** is also not a verb. Maybe I misunderstood your sentence? Which is the verb you refer to?

Comment: I don't care whatever it is called @virolino, but the page cited claims it is wrong, which is misleading. I don't know what you mean by "unfortunate choice"; I believe it's pretty common and is more natural than the cumbersome 'his or her'.

Comment: @user178049: unfortunate choice = a plural form is used for singular. It fixes one problem, (potentially) creating another.

Comment: @virolino but is less problematic, of course, than "his", which is said to be biased towards male, and "his or her", which is just stylistically ugly.

Comment: @user178049: actually, it is more politically correct, **at the cost of being** (potentially) **problematic**.

Comment: @virolino pronoun, not verb, sorry

Comment: @BellaSwan: exactly my thought :)

Answer (score -2):

logically "every" means all of them, which should connotate "they".  Every person on the beach would be collectively referred to as they.  If the intent is to address each element of the collective, then use "each" instead of "every".  Therefore use "it" for each and "they" for every.

This is more logical.  The previous explanation is convoluted and mixed the two together.  IMHO.

Comment: Nope. "Everything" roughly means "each thing", not "all the things", and the grammar reflects this. You would never say, "*Everyone on the beach **were**...*"